# Inserting an element at the end of a linked list?

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, runtime-error

What is the problem in this implementation of 'insert an element at the end of simple linked list' when passed the head of the list?

```
void insert (int x, cel *ini) {
    cel *tmp = ini;
    while (tmp != NULL)
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    cel *new = malloc(sizeof(cel));
    new->value = x;
    tmp->prox = new;
    new->prox = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of the code and what the problem you're having is.

Comment: The while loop iterates until tmp is null, then you try to dereference a null pointer. You have to loop until tmp->prox is null.

Comment: You don't check that the `malloc()` is successful — that's a problem.  How do you add the first element to the list?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful to you: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/

Comment: That's a very nice tutorial, @dkb :D

Comment: This is helpful reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . Here, before posting your question you've not discovered that `tmp` is NULL, so you probably haven't yet learnt how to investigate/debug properly.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
void insert (int x, cel *ini) {
   cel *tmp = ini;cel *left;
   while (tmp != NULL)
   { 
       left = temp;
       tmp = tmp->prox;
   }
   cel *new =(cel*) malloc(sizeof(cel));
   new->value = x;
   left->prox = new;
   new->prox = NULL;
}
```

You are checking until `tmp` is null, and then you add `tmp->prox=new`. But the problem is that current temp is NULL. You need to point to new node from the previous node of temp.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the condition in the while loop to:

```
while(tmp->prox!=NULL)
```

It will work just fine as you have to reach the last node of the current linked list which points to NULL.

But you need to add the following condition to check if ini is NULL, for that, add the following **before** the loop.

```
if(ini==NULL)
{
cel *new = malloc(sizeof(cel));
new->value = x;
new->prox = NULL;
ini=new;
 }
```

What your program is doing is reaching NULL (tmp of your program is NULL )

Comment: what if *ini is null?

Comment: Well, yes You will have to add a seperate condition for that.. I've made the necessary changes in the answer.